# Update 32 bit code to read a value from the registry to run in either 32 bit or 64 bit

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have code from [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0015.htm) that reads a value from the registry. I am trying to make the code work in both 32 and 64 bit versions of MS Access.

```vb
    '********Code Start**************
    'This code was originally written by Terry Kreft
    ' and Dev Ashish. 
    'It is not to be altered or distributed, 
    'except as part of an application. 
    'You are free to use it in any application,  
    'provided the copyright notice is left unchanged.
    '
    'Code Courtesy of
    'Dev Ashish & Terry Kreft
    '
    Public Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000
    Public Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
    Public Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    Public Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
    Public Const HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA = &H80000004
    Public Const HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = &H80000005
    Public Const HKEY_DYN_DATA = &H80000006
    
    Private Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = &H20000
    Private Const KEY_QUERY_VALUE = &H1&
    Private Const KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS = &H8&
    Private Const KEY_NOTIFY = &H10&
    Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
    Private Const KEY_READ = ((STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ Or _
                            KEY_QUERY_VALUE Or _
                            KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS Or _
                            KEY_NOTIFY) And _
                            (Not SYNCHRONIZE))
    Private Const MAXLEN = 256
    Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS = &H0&
    
    Const REG_NONE = 0
    Const REG_SZ = 1
    Const REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2
    Const REG_BINARY = 3
    Const REG_DWORD = 4
    Const REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN = 4
    Const REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN = 5
    Const REG_LINK = 6
    Const REG_MULTI_SZ = 7
    Const REG_RESOURCE_LIST = 8
    
    Type FILETIME
        dwLowDateTime As Long
        dwHighDateTime As Long
    End Type
    
    Private Declare Function apiRegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
            Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, _
            ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, _
            ByVal samDesired As Long, ByRef phkResult As Long) _
            As Long
    
    Private Declare Function apiRegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
            Alias "RegCloseKey" (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long
    
    Private Declare Function apiRegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
            Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, _
            ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal lpReserved As Long, _
            ByRef lpType As Long, lpData As Any, _
            ByRef lpcbData As Long) As Long
    
    Private Declare Function apiRegQueryInfoKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
            Alias "RegQueryInfoKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, _
            ByVal lpClass As String, ByRef lpcbClass As Long, _
            ByVal lpReserved As Long, ByRef lpcSubKeys As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbMaxSubKeyLen As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbMaxClassLen As Long, _
            ByRef lpcValues As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbMaxValueNameLen As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbMaxValueLen As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbSecurityDescriptor As Long, _
            ByRef lpftLastWriteTime As FILETIME) As Long
    
    Function fReturnRegKeyValue(ByVal lngKeyToGet As Long, _
                                ByVal strKeyName As String, _
                                ByVal strValueName As String) _
                                As String
    Dim lnghKey As Long
    Dim strClassName As String
    Dim lngClassLen As Long
    Dim lngReserved As Long
    Dim lngSubKeys As Long
    Dim lngMaxSubKeyLen As Long
    Dim lngMaxClassLen As Long
    Dim lngValues As Long
    Dim lngMaxValueNameLen As Long
    Dim lngMaxValueLen As Long
    Dim lngSecurity As Long
    Dim ftLastWrite As FILETIME
    Dim lngType As Long
    Dim lngData As Long
    Dim lngTmp As Long
    Dim strRet As String
    Dim varRet As Variant
    Dim lngRet As Long
        
        On Error GoTo fReturnRegKeyValue_Err
            
        'Open the key first
        lngTmp = apiRegOpenKeyEx(lngKeyToGet, _
                    strKeyName, 0&, KEY_READ, lnghKey)
    
        'Are we ok?
        If Not (lngTmp = ERROR_SUCCESS) Then Err.Raise _
                                    lngTmp + vbObjectError
    
        lngReserved = 0&
        strClassName = String$(MAXLEN, 0):  lngClassLen = MAXLEN
    
        'Get boundary values
        lngTmp = apiRegQueryInfoKey(lnghKey, strClassName, _
            lngClassLen, lngReserved, lngSubKeys, lngMaxSubKeyLen, _
            lngMaxClassLen, lngValues, lngMaxValueNameLen, _
            lngMaxValueLen, lngSecurity, ftLastWrite)
    
        'How we doin?
        If Not (lngTmp = ERROR_SUCCESS) Then Err.Raise _
                                    lngTmp + vbObjectError
        
        'Now grab the value for the key
        strRet = String$(MAXLEN - 1, 0)
        lngTmp = apiRegQueryValueEx(lnghKey, strValueName, _
                    lngReserved, lngType, ByVal strRet, lngData)
        Select Case lngType
          Case REG_SZ
            lngTmp = apiRegQueryValueEx(lnghKey, strValueName, _
                    lngReserved, lngType, ByVal strRet, lngData)
            varRet = Left(strRet, lngData - 1)
          Case REG_DWORD
            lngTmp = apiRegQueryValueEx(lnghKey, strValueName, _
                    lngReserved, lngType, lngRet, lngData)
            varRet = lngRet
          Case REG_BINARY
            lngTmp = apiRegQueryValueEx(lnghKey, strValueName, _
                    lngReserved, lngType, ByVal strRet, lngData)
            varRet = Left(strRet, lngData)
        End Select
        
        'All quiet on the western front?
        If Not (lngTmp = ERROR_SUCCESS) Then Err.Raise _
                                    lngTmp + vbObjectError
    
    fReturnRegKeyValue_Exit:
        fReturnRegKeyValue = varRet
        lngTmp = apiRegCloseKey(lnghKey)
        Exit Function
    fReturnRegKeyValue_Err:
        varRet = "Error: Key or Value Not Found."
        Resume fReturnRegKeyValue_Exit
    End Function
    
    '********Code End**************
```

I tried the following, since I understood that I need to add `#If Win64` and change all those declared functions to `PtrSafe`:

```vb
    Option Compare Database
    Option Explicit
    
    '********Code Start**************
    'This code was originally written by Terry Kreft
    ' and Dev Ashish.
    'It is not to be altered or distributed,
    'except as part of an application.
    'You are free to use it in any application,
    'provided the copyright notice is left unchanged.
    '
    'Code Courtesy of
    'Dev Ashish & Terry Kreft
    'http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0015.htm
    
    
    Public Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000
    Public Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
    Public Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    Public Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
    Public Const HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA = &H80000004
    Public Const HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = &H80000005
    Public Const HKEY_DYN_DATA = &H80000006
    
    Private Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = &H20000
    Private Const KEY_QUERY_VALUE = &H1&
    Private Const KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS = &H8&
    Private Const KEY_NOTIFY = &H10&
    Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
    Private Const KEY_READ = ((STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ Or _
                            KEY_QUERY_VALUE Or _
                            KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS Or _
                            KEY_NOTIFY) And _
                            (Not SYNCHRONIZE))
    Private Const MAXLEN = 256
    Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS = &H0&
    
    Const REG_NONE = 0
    Const REG_SZ = 1
    Const REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2
    Const REG_BINARY = 3
    Const REG_DWORD = 4
    Const REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN = 4
    Const REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN = 5
    Const REG_LINK = 6
    Const REG_MULTI_SZ = 7
    Const REG_RESOURCE_LIST = 8
    
    Type FILETIME
        dwLowDateTime As Long
        dwHighDateTime As Long
    End Type
    
    #If Win64 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiRegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, _
                ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, _
                ByVal samDesired As LongPtr, ByRef phkResult As LongPtr) _
                As Long
        
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiRegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                Alias "RegCloseKey" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr) As Long
        
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiRegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, _
                ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal lpReserved As LongPtr, _
                ByRef lpType As LongPtr, lpData As Any, _
                ByRef lpcbData As LongPtr) As Long
        
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiRegQueryInfoKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
                Alias "RegQueryInfoKeyA" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, _
                ByVal lpClass As String, ByRef lpcbClass As LongPtr, _
                ByVal lpReserved As LongPtr, ByRef lpcSubKeys As LongPtr, _
                ByRef lpcbMaxSubKeyLen As LongPtr, _
                ByRef lpcbMaxClassLen As LongPtr, _
                ByRef lpcValues As LongPtr, _
                ByRef lpcbMaxValueNameLen As LongPtr, _
                ByRef lpcbMaxValueLen As LongPtr, _
                ByRef lpcbSecurityDescriptor As LongPtr, _
                ByRef lpftLastWriteTime As FILETIME) As Long
            
    #Else
    Private Declare Function apiRegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
            Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, _
            ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, _
            ByVal samDesired As Long, ByRef phkResult As Long) _
            As Long
    
    Private Declare Function apiRegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
            Alias "RegCloseKey" (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long
    
    Private Declare Function apiRegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
            Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, _
            ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal lpReserved As Long, _
            ByRef lpType As Long, lpData As Any, _
            ByRef lpcbData As Long) As Long
    
    Private Declare Function apiRegQueryInfoKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
            Alias "RegQueryInfoKeyA" (ByVal hKey As Long, _
            ByVal lpClass As String, ByRef lpcbClass As Long, _
            ByVal lpReserved As Long, ByRef lpcSubKeys As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbMaxSubKeyLen As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbMaxClassLen As Long, _
            ByRef lpcValues As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbMaxValueNameLen As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbMaxValueLen As Long, _
            ByRef lpcbSecurityDescriptor As Long, _
            ByRef lpftLastWriteTime As FILETIME) As Long
    #End If
    
    Function fReturnRegKeyValue(ByVal lngKeyToGet As Long, _
                                ByVal strKeyName As String, _
                                ByVal strValueName As String) _
                                As String
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim lnghKey As LongPtr
        Dim lngClassLen As LongPtr
        Dim lngReserved As LongPtr
        Dim lngSubKeys As LongPtr
        Dim lngMaxSubKeyLen As LongPtr
        Dim lngMaxClassLen As LongPtr
        Dim lngValues As LongPtr
        Dim lngMaxValueNameLen As LongPtr
        Dim lngMaxValueLen As LongPtr
        Dim lngSecurity As LongPtr
        Dim lngType As LongPtr
        Dim lngRet As LongPtr
        'Dim lngData As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim lnghKey As Long
        Dim lngClassLen As Long
        Dim lngReserved As Long
        Dim lngSubKeys As Long
        Dim lngMaxSubKeyLen As Long
        Dim lngMaxClassLen As Long
        Dim lngValues As Long
        Dim lngMaxValueNameLen As Long
        Dim lngMaxValueLen As Long
        Dim lngSecurity As Long
        Dim lngType As Long
        Dim lngRet As Long
        'Dim lngData As Long
    #End If
    
    'Dim lngData As Long
    Dim lngTmp As Long
    Dim strClassName As String
    Dim ftLastWrite As FILETIME
    Dim strRet As String
    Dim varRet As Variant
        
        On Error GoTo fReturnRegKeyValue_Err
            
        'Open the key first
        lngTmp = apiRegOpenKeyEx(lngKeyToGet, _
                    strKeyName, 0&, KEY_READ, lnghKey)
    
        'Are we ok?
        If Not (lngTmp = ERROR_SUCCESS) Then Err.Raise _
                                    lngTmp + vbObjectError
    
        lngReserved = 0&
        strClassName = String$(MAXLEN, 0):  lngClassLen = MAXLEN
    
        'Get boundary values
        lngTmp = apiRegQueryInfoKey(lnghKey, strClassName, _
            lngClassLen, lngReserved, lngSubKeys, lngMaxSubKeyLen, _
            lngMaxClassLen, lngValues, lngMaxValueNameLen, _
            lngMaxValueLen, lngSecurity, ftLastWrite)
    
        'How we doin?
        If Not (lngTmp = ERROR_SUCCESS) Then Err.Raise _
                                    lngTmp + vbObjectError
        
        'Now grab the value for the key
        strRet = String$(MAXLEN - 1, 0)
        lngTmp = apiRegQueryValueEx(lnghKey, strValueName, _
                    lngReserved, lngType, ByVal strRet, lngData)
        Select Case lngType
          Case REG_SZ
            lngTmp = apiRegQueryValueEx(lnghKey, strValueName, _
                    lngReserved, lngType, ByVal strRet, lngData)
            varRet = Left(strRet, lngData - 1)
          Case REG_DWORD
            lngTmp = apiRegQueryValueEx(lnghKey, strValueName, _
                    lngReserved, lngType, lngRet, lngData)
            varRet = lngRet
          Case REG_BINARY
            lngTmp = apiRegQueryValueEx(lnghKey, strValueName, _
                    lngReserved, lngType, ByVal strRet, lngData)
            varRet = Left(strRet, lngData)
        End Select
        
        'All quiet on the western front?
        If Not (lngTmp = ERROR_SUCCESS) Then Err.Raise _
                                    lngTmp + vbObjectError
    
    fReturnRegKeyValue_Exit:
        fReturnRegKeyValue = varRet
        lngTmp = apiRegCloseKey(lnghKey)
        Exit Function
    fReturnRegKeyValue_Err:
        varRet = "Error: Key or Value Not Found."
        Resume fReturnRegKeyValue_Exit
    End Function
```

I am stuck with the variable `lngData`.

If I set it to LongPtr for Win64 I get a Type Mismatch error on the line

```
varRet = Left(strRet, lngData - 1)
```

If I leave it as Long always, I get a ByRef Argument Type Mismatch on the line

```
lngTmp = apiRegQueryValueEx(lnghKey, strValueName, lngReserved, lngType, ByVal strRet, lngData)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every *Long* argument should be *LongPtr*:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiRegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, _
        ByVal samDesired As Long, ByRef phkResult As LongPtr) _
        As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiRegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        Alias "RegCloseKey" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiRegQueryValueEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        Alias "RegQueryValueExA" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal lpReserved As LongPtr, _
        ByRef lpType As Long, lpData As Any, _
        ByRef lpcbData As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiRegQueryInfoKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
        Alias "RegQueryInfoKeyA" (ByVal hKey As LongPtr, _
        ByVal lpClass As String, ByRef lpcbClass As Long, _
        ByVal lpReserved As LongPtr, ByRef lpcSubKeys As Long, _
        ByRef lpcbMaxSubKeyLen As Long, _
        ByRef lpcbMaxClassLen As Long, _
        ByRef lpcValues As Long, _
        ByRef lpcbMaxValueNameLen As Long, _
        ByRef lpcbMaxValueLen As Long, _
        ByRef lpcbSecurityDescriptor As Long, _
        ByRef lpftLastWriteTime As FILETIME) As Long
```

Comment: How would you determine which should be LongPtr or Long?

Comment: From here: [Office 2010 User Resources - PDF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17410)

Comment: I downloaded the files, but can't find anything related to 64 bit LongPtr.
I have been reading [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-msoffice_custom-mso_2013_release/regopenkeyex-for-32-and-64-bit/81e1143d-9ca2-455b-91ec-5c2430bf43d1?auth=1) and it mentions that LongPtr should only be set for pointers, but still unsure how to identify which is actually a pointer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, picked the wrong URL: [Office 2010 Help Files: Win32API_PtrSafe with 64-bit Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/win32api_ptrsafe-with-64-bit-support?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: Rummaging through those files I found the [win32API_PtrSafe.txt](https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/WinAPI-4-VBA/blob/master/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt) and searched for the alias names and found the exact same parameter list and names. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691831(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) also helped a bit.
So I would only change the declaration section including adding the word PtrSafe and changing the parameters datatype and not the variable declaration?

Comment: I haven't checked your variables, but they must match the type of the arguments they are supposed to be passed to.

Comment: Makes sense. I understand that PtrSafe was introduced in Office 2010. I am enclosing the code with PtrSafe and LongPtr in `#If Win64` and using the original code in `#else`, becuase there might be some 2007 versions around.